# Export Visual Studios 08 project to PDA

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I have got a visual studios 2008 application which is deisnged for a PDA. How do i export the project to run on the PDA. The PDA is running windows mobile 6.

Comment: By "export"  I'm guessing you mean "compile?"

Comment: I want to deploy it onto the PDA so that it is installed and running on the PDA

Comment: And you don't know how to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html) and deploy a CAB file using an Installer project in Studio.